# Is there a way to get the macro value for a given library

Tags: c, memory-management, macros, c-preprocessor

I have situation as below:

```
#define CONSTANT 123
foo()
{
...
}
```

Using the above code, after creating the library lets say test.so, how can get to know the CONSTANT macro value from the library? Is there any way?

Comment: You'll need a `get_constant()` function for the library. Macros are gone after the first step of the build.

Comment: Thanks @Baldrick. It worked the way I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the constant in a header file and supply that header with the library.

Comment: This is something not to let the outsider know so sharing header may not work for me. Only if developer wants to know the value should be able to get the value with running anything other prog.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do that:

- Define the constant in a header file to the library and distribute it with the library
- Make the library some form of open source
- Write a dedicated `get_constant` function that returns the value

Its worth noting that Macros are always sheer text replacement. So after compile time you won't even know they were there.

Comment: Open Source is a kind of distribution of software. Designing an interface is programming technik. Don't mix both because it would confuse readers. -- But if you think you can provide the source code to the reader then you failed to provide an interface.

Comment: @harper Making the library open source would allow users to find constant names, however, which is what OP wants

Comment: Open Source is a relegion that requires to make your work public. There are other possibiliies to provide source code to the customer. Defining the version in the header is a more sensible option.